# retrieve id from dynamically created row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page that displays information from my database. I need the user to be able to click the "details" link to view more information pertaining to the record, or click an input box ("check" column), then submit, which will update the status of the record. To achieve this I need to get the id from the "id" column.

this is what the page looks like:

[image: req page]

and this is the code that creates it:

```
  $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "lib/req.reqinfo.php",
async: false,
data: {},
success: function(response){
// alert(response);
    var responseArray = response.split(',');    
    for(var x=0;x<responseArray.length;x++){
        id = responseArray[x]; x++;
        dateadded = responseArray[x]; x++;
        needby = responseArray[x]; x++;
        addedby = responseArray[x]; x++;
        unit = responseArray[x]; x++;
        appr = responseArray[x];

        $("#dbinfo").append('<br /><div class="row"><div id="idrow'+x+'" class="onecol bg">'+id+'</div><div class="twocol bg">'+dateadded+'</div><div class="twocol bg">'+needby+'</div><div class="twocol bg">'+addedby+'</div><div class="twocol bg">'+unit+'</div><div class="onecol bg">'+appr+'</div><div class="onecol bg"><label id="detaillink" class="link"><a href="#">details</a></label></div><div class="onecol bg last">'+check+'</div></div>');
    }
```

I can't seem to find a solution to point to that particular div to extract the needed information

html:

```
    <div class="container">
   <br />
<div id="dbinfo" class="row center">
<div class="onecol bg">ID</div>
<div class="twocol bg">Date Added</div>
<div class="twocol bg">Need By</div>
<div class="twocol bg">Added By</div>
<div class="twocol bg">Unit #</div>
<div class="onecol bg">Appr.</div>
<div class="onecol bg">Details</div>
<div class="onecol bg last">check</div>
<div class="onecol"> &nbsp </div>
</div>

   <br />
<div class="row">
    <label class="link"><a href="home.php">Home</a></label>
</div>
```

Comment: This JS code just generates that div "table" and there is no code for finding the ID col. right?

Comment: ok, I edited it

and yes, it just generates the div table

Comment: You know that building table from divs is a crime?) Check the answer

Comment: Just FYI, you can use this `appr = responseArray[x++];` instead of calling `x++;` at the end of each line. In the first part, it uses the value `x` to index the array, **then** increments its value for future use. It may not be applicable everywhere, but this is simple enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach..

Add the class details to this

```
<div class="onecol bg details">Details</div>

// Assuming the details cell has a class called details.
$('.details').on('click', function(){
    var $row = $(this).closest('div.row');

    var id = $row.find('div:eq(0)').attr('id');
    // This is the id you are looking for
});
```

---

```
.attr('id');  If that div has a id..

.html();     If you are looking for the text inside it
```

Comment: Probably: `.text(); If you are looking for the text inside it`

Comment: got it:

     <div id="idrow" class="onecol bg">

     var id = $row.find('div:eq(0)').text();

just a couple changes to what you suggested, and I'm in business, thank you sir

Comment: @Brendan .. glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Because you are generating the "rows" yourself, you can directly add the id inline. For example:

```
<div class="onecol bg"><label id="detaillink" class="link"><a href="#" data-id="'+x+'>details</a></label></div>
```

or:

```
<div class="onecol bg" data-id="'+x+'>Details</div>
```

btw my personal choice would be to present such tabular data in a table, and attach the click behavior to the row (tr).

Comment: No matter how the stuff is presented, I agree with using the `data-*` attributes

Answer (score 0):

In html:

- Link doesn't need a label.
- Link need some class to easier selection for further event handling

The event handler for link:

```
$('link class').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).parents('div').siblings('div:eq(0)').text();
});
```